# Bank of England base rate feed

Tags: interest-rates

I am implementing a program in Java that needs the Bank of England base rate. Rather than the user inputting this into the system, I have heard that there is a way to get a **live feed** of the base rate directly from (I am guessing) the Bank of England (i.e. gets automatically updated). Has anyone heard of or used something similar? - any advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but they keep it updated on their homepage.

http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/

The Current Bank Rate is shown in the top of the box in the bottom right corner!

Comment: Thanks for getting back. However, I am looking for a way to link the base rate into my program so it automatically changes with a rate change (rather than having to manually change it every time) - I have been told that there is a way but haven't heard from anyone who has used it.

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry it wasn't what you were looking for! Good luck in your search!

Comment: There is an interactive database at http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/mfsd/iadb/NewInterMed.asp?Travel=NIxIRxSUx Maybe you could generate a script to download from that database automagically.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by *Owe*, you could use the *Statistics* part of the *BoE* website. It's not like the rate is changing every second, so you don't really need a **live** feed, I suppose.

You could update it on every start - for example using the [Interest and Exchange Rates tables](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/mfsd/iadb/index.asp?Travel=NIxSTxTIx&levels=1&XNotes=Y&G0Xtop.x=44&G0Xtop.y=13&C=13T&XNotes2=Y&Nodes=X3687X3688X3691X3694X3716X3738X3754X3757X3764X3771X3774&SectionRequired=I&HideNums=-1&ExtraInfo=false#BM). Just generate the format you like, and download/import it to your program. For instance, here's a direct link to [daily data in CSV](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/mfsd/iadb/fromshowcolumns.asp?Travel=NIxSTxTIxSUx&FromSeries=1&ToSeries=50&DAT=ALL&VFD=Y&csv.x=8&csv.y=26&CSVF=TT&C=13T&Filter=N). Parsing it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link provided to daily data in CSV by Karol is no longer valid. This is of course the problem with relying on a third party data source / parsing web pages / etc. when there is no published commitment from the author (BofE in this case) to maintain the data in that format into the future. The data cannot easily be linked to as it is client-side generated in jQuery. See: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp